# Can a player ever lose her or his rating (voluntarily)?

Tags: rating, fide

I am just curious. Is it possible for a rated player to quit his association with FIDE and start afresh, as an unrated player?

Comment: Use a new name...

Comment: The timing and similarity to the previous question makes me suspect that he did.

Answer (score 3):

I found FIDE regulations 7.21 which state:

> Players whose ratings drop below 1000 are listed on the next list as
>   ‘delisted’. Thereafter, they are treated in the same manner as any
>   other unrated player.

This sounds like a "reset" to me.

Note that this is different to an *inactive* player which you become after not playing rated games for a year. However in the case of inactive players you retain your rating.

Other than this "delisting" I don't think there is a way to lose your rating.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the simple answer is no, you cannot reset your rating and start again.

This discussion was had at the link posted below a few years ago:
http://www.ecforum.org.uk/viewtopic.php?t=3689

I cannot find anything referencing resetting rating on the http://www.fide.com website.

Comment: I found FIDE regulations 7.21 which state: "Players whose ratings drop below 1000 are listed on the next list as ‘delisted’. Thereafter, they are treated in the same manner as any other unrated player." This sounds like a "reset" to me.

Comment: @user1583209: you should post this as an answer and get yourself some sweet rep!

Comment: @Bad_Bishop Done

Answer (score 0):

There is no way that a player can lose his rating. If it happens then there are several ways of mistaken identities that can occur in the chess world. Even if a player explicitly tries doing it can even lead to corporal punishments and FIDE will ban his entire chess career.